# Nonetype has no attribute Next

Tags: python, linked-list, nonetype

```
class Solution:
    def removeNthFromEnd(self, head: Optional[ListNode], n: int) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        ptr1 = head
        ptr2 = head
        count = 0
        while ptr1:
            count += 1
            ptr1 = ptr1.next
        count = count - n
        for i in range(count):
            ptr2 = ptr2.next
        ptr2.next = ptr2.next.next
        return head
```

The problem is asking me to remove the nth node counting from the end of a singly linked list, but I keep getting nonetype has no attribute next for the line "ptr2.next = ptr.next.next" and I don't know what's wrong

image for reference:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqEZZ.png)

I have tried other methods of solving this problem and the ptr2.next = ptr2.next.next did not result in this error. The other method was moving one pointer by n, and then moving both pointers until the first pointer is at the end, therefore positioning the second pointer right before the node we want to delete.

Comment: What was the value of `n` when this happened.

Comment: first test case had n = 2 with a list of 5 nodes

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine..!

just debug the edge cases!!

```
class Solution:
    def removeNthFromEnd(self, head: Optional[ListNode], n: int) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        
        ptr1 = head
        ptr2 = head
        count = 0
        while ptr1:
            count += 1
            ptr1 = ptr1.next
        count = count - n
        if count:
            for i in range(count-1):
                ptr2 = ptr2.next
            ptr2.next = ptr2.next.next
            return head
        else:   #When you wanted to remove first element in the linked list!!
            return head.next
```

**Edgecase1:**

```
head = [1], n = 1  desired output: []
```

in my code the else part will run and head.next will result be an empty list!!

**Other point-** is that ptr2 is basically pointing the first value you need to iterate `(count-1)` and at that time you will be at `(N-1)th node` and then do the same `ptr2.next = ptr2.next.next`..

Answer (score 1):

```
count = count - n
for i in range(count):
    ptr2 = ptr2.next
```

This loop advances `ptr2` one step too far.

`ptr2` ends up pointing at the node to be removed, but that's wrong, because you actually want to modify the node *before* that.